# ¿Por qué rand() genera los mismos números aleatorios en un ciclo, aún si se establece una semilla?

Tags: c++, punteros

Dentro de un ciclo, necesito generar índices aleatorios para obtener información desde listas. El problema es que estos índices son iguales con cada ejecución.

Esto causa que la información se repita. Que la información se repita no es un problema, pero en este caso, se repite en casi todas las iteraciones del ciclo. (Si son 10000 iteraciones en el ciclo, la primera genera índices aleatorios correctos, y las 9999 restantes generan índices iguales).

¿Que podría estar causando que los números aleatorios sean iguales casi siempre?

```
void generar_humanos(lista_humanos * listahumanos, Lista_ID * lista_id,int cantidad_humanos,string * Nombres, string * Apellidos, string * Paises,
                 string * Profesiones, string * Creencias){
    NodoDoble * temp = lista_id->primerNodo;
    int x = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    while (x!=cantidad_humanos){
        if(temp==nullptr)
            break;
        else{
            string nom = Nombres[rand()%1600];
            string ape = Apellidos[rand()%1301];
            string pais = Paises[rand()%195];
            string cree =  Creencias[rand()%22];
            string profe = Profesiones[rand()%105];

            Humano * humano = new Humano(nom,ape,pais,cree,profe,"correo","hoy",temp->dato);

            listahumanos->insertar_al_final(humano);
            x++;
            Sleep(0.1);
            temp = temp->siguiente;
            cout << "Apellido: " << humano->Apellido << humano->id << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Llamando a la función

```
generar_humanos(lista_personas,lista,10000,Nombres,Apellidos,Paises,Profesiones,Creencias);
```

Genera el siguiente resultado:

[image: captura mostrando "Apellido: Lloyd" y luego un id muchas veces]

El primer índice aleatorio se genera correctamente, pero en el resto de iteraciones del ciclo se genera el mismo, por lo que se repite el Apellido "Lloyd" 9999 veces.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la función `insertar_al_final` no recibe el puntero `humano` por referencia y lo reasignas incorrectamente por alguna razón? Prueba a imprimir `ape` en vez de `humano->apellido`, para discriminar que el problema sea de `rand()`.

Comment: Lo he probado como has dicho, pero es la misma situación.

Comment: Para ignorar algún problema con pasar `ape` por referencia a `humano` (quién sabe), y luego esta dirección por referencia a `insertar_al_final`, prueba a imprimir directamente el índice generado, es decir:

`int idx = rand() % 1301; std::cout << idx << std::endl; ape = apellidos[idx];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206780/is-srandtimenull-bad

Comment: @SJuan76 Aunque se produzca desbordamiento, el nuevo valor es una semilla válida. No afecta el por qué `rand()` no está devolviendo una secuencia pseudoaleatoria.

Comment: Prueba también a pasar el `srand` al `main`, para que afecte a todo el programa y no solo a esa función. Pero me da que es un problema de la implementación de `rand()` que estas utilizando. ¿Qué compilador utilizas?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo tiene `Apellidos`?

Comment: El compilador es MinGW 5.3.0 32 bit

Comment: @Peregring-lk He pasado srand al main pero no ha cambiado. También he probado imprimiendo los indices generados y todos son iguales.

Comment: @SJuan76 Vale, pero eso solo afectaría a la secuencia en diferentes ejecuciones. Aquí, la secuencia no es aleatoria en la misma ejecución. Incluso con la semilla por defecto (`1`), debería generar una secuencia pseudoaleatoria uniformemente distribuída.

Comment: @SJuan76 He probado lo que has dicho, para cuatro ejecuciones, estos son los valores de seed:

Comment: 1477779041
1477779053
1477779064
1477779074

Comment: @David.80004 ¿Es `apellidos` el único valor que se está repitiendo? ¿nombre, país, creencias, etc, están generandose bien? La única sospecha que me queda es el valor de módulo que estás utilizando.

Comment: @Peregring-Ik De hecho se repite para todos, no solo para apellidos.

Comment: Deberías poder poner un ejemplo de código mínimo y que compile donde se reproduzca el comportamiento.

Comment: ¿Has probado con diferentes configuraciones de optimización del compilador? Tiene pinta de que el compilador está optimizando el bucle re-utilizando índices y [des-enroscando el bucle](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenroscado_de_bucles).

Answer (score 1):

C++ no dispone de un sistema de generación de números aleatorios propios sino que son pseudo aleatorios. Esta es la razón por la que hace falta proporcionar una semilla que haga difícil la predicción de los números a obtener.

Cada vez que llamas a

```
srand(time(0));
```

Estas indicando una semilla para generar números aleatorios. La generación de los números aleatorios se basa única y exclusivamente en la semilla actual, luego para una misma semilla de obtendrá siempre el mismo número aleatorio.

Para simplificar la generación de números aleatorios, cada llamada a `rand()` actualiza la semilla.

Dicho todo esto, para generar números diferentes asegúrate de proporcionar la semilla una sola vez.

Answer (score 0):

La llamada a

```
srand(time(0));
```

no la hagas dentro de la función,
puedes llamarla por ejemplo en cuanto inicia tu programa pero sólo una vez.